# Python loop to iterate through elements in an XML and get sub-elements values

Tags: python, xml, api, urllib2, minidom

I am working with an XML being read from aN API that has several hotel locations. Each individual hotel has a "hotel code" element that is a value  unique to each hotel in the XML output and I would like to GET the "latitude" and "longitude" attributes for each hotel. My code right now can parse through the XML and record each instance of "latitude" and "longitude" but not organized as paired lat/lon for a hotel, rather it records every latitude in the XML then every longitude in the XML. I am having trouble figuring out how to say: IF hotel code == the previous hotel code, record latitude/longitude together; ELSE move on to next hotel and record that lat/lon. An example section of the XML output is below as is my code and my code's output:

XML:

```
<hotel code="13272" name="Sonesta Fort Lauderdale Beach" categoryCode="4EST" categoryName="4 STARS" destinationCode="FLL" destinationName="Fort Lauderdale - Hollywood Area - FL" zoneCode="1" zoneName="Fort Lauderdale Beach Area" latitude="26.137508" longitude="-80.103438" minRate="1032.10" maxRate="1032.10" currency="USD"><rooms><room code="DBL.DX" name="DOUBLE DELUXE"><rates><rate rateKey="20161215|20161220|W|235|13272|DBL.DX|GC-ALL|RO||1~1~0||N@675BEABED1984D9E8073EB6154B41AEE" rateClass="NOR" rateType="BOOKABLE" net="1032.10" allotment="238" rateCommentsId="235|38788|431" paymentType="AT_WEB" packaging="false" boardCode="RO" boardName="ROOM ONLY" rooms="1" adults="1" children="0"><cancellationPolicies><cancellationPolicy amount="206.42" from="2016-12-11T23:59:00-05:00"/></cancellationPolicies></rate></rates></room></rooms></hotel>
```

CODE:

```
import time, hashlib
import urllib2
from xml.dom import minidom

# Your API Key and secret
apiKey =
Secret =

# Signature is generated by SHA256 (Api-Key + Secret + Timestamp (in seconds))
sigStr = "%s%s%d" % (apiKey,Secret,int(time.time()))
signature = hashlib.sha256(sigStr).hexdigest()

endpoint = "https://api.test.hotelbeds.com/hotel-api/1.0/hotels"

try:
    # Create http request and add headers
    req = urllib2.Request(url=endpoint)
    req.add_header("X-Signature", signature)
    req.add_header("Api-Key", apiKey)
    req.add_header("Accept", "application/xml")
    req.add_header("Content-Type", "application/xml")
    req.add_data(' <availabilityRQ xmlns="http://www.hotelbeds.com/schemas/messages" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ><stay checkIn="2016-12-15" checkOut="2016-12-20"/><occupancies><occupancy rooms="1" adults="1" children="0"/></occupancies><geolocation longitude="-80.265323" latitude="26.131510" radius="10" unit="km"/></availabilityRQ>')

    # Reading response and print-out
    file = minidom.parse(urllib2.urlopen(req))
    hotels = file.getElementsByTagName("hotel")
    lat = [items.attributes['latitude'].value for items in hotels]
    lon = [items.attributes['longitude'].value for items in hotels]
    print lat + lon

except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
    # Reading body of response
    httpResonponse = e.read()
    print "%s, reason: %s " % (str(e), httpResonponse)
except urllib2.URLError, e:
    print "Client error: %s" % e.reason
except Exception, e:
    print "General exception: %s " % str(e)
```

MY OUTPUT RIGHT NOW:

[u'26.144224', u'26.122569', u'26.11437', u'26.1243414605478', u'26.119195', u'26.1942424979814', u'26.145488', u'26.1632044819114', u'26.194145', u'26.1457688280936', u'26.1868547339183', u'26.1037652256159', u'26.090442389015', u'26.187242', u'-80.325579', u'-80.251829', u'-80.25315', u'-80.2564349700697', u'-80.262738', u'-80.2919112076052', u'-80.258274', u'-80.2584546734579', u'-80.261252', u'-80.2576325763948', u'-80.1963213016279', u'-80.2630081633106', u'-80.2272565662588', u'-80.20161000000002']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could place the result of your XML file in to an iterable structure like a dictionary.
I've taken your sample xml data and placed it into a file called hotels.xml.

```
from xml.dom import minidom

hotels_position = {}

dom = minidom.parse('hotels.xml')
hotels = dom.getElementsByTagName("hotel")

for hotel in hotels:
    hotel_id = hotel.attributes['code'].value
    position = {}
    position['latitude'] = hotel.attributes['latitude'].value
    position['longitude'] = hotel.attributes['longitude'].value
    hotels_position[hotel_id] = position

print(hotels_position)
```

This code outputs the following structure (I added a second hotel)

```
{u'13272': {'latitude': u'26.137508', 'longitude': u'-80.103438'}, u'13273': {'latitude': u'26.137508', 'longitude': u'-80.103438'}}
```

You can now iterate through each hotel in the dictionary.

```
for hotel in hotels_position:
    print("Hotel {} is located at ({},{})".format(hotel,
                                                  hotels_position[hotel]['latitude'],
                                                  hotels_position[hotel]['latitude']))
```

Now that you have your data in an organised structure, your 'logic' will be much easier to write.

Comment: Thanks Scotty! I believe your solution worked well. Instead of placing the result into a .xml file I was actually able to read directly from the API request output using the

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally hit the enter key... Anyways, I was able to use the         file = minidom.parse(urllib2.urlopen(req))                                              hotels = file.getElementsByTagName("hotel")                                                          to parse through the data and build the dictionary. The code makes an API request every time it is run. Thanks again for your help

Comment: Great. I onlyh placed the data in a file since I don't have access to the API. Glad it works for you.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how would I add another element attribute to this dictionary? For example, in the API response XML there there is an attribute called "allotment": <hotels><hotel><rooms><room><rates><rate><allotment>. I'm trying to reverse-engineer your solution to include this data in my output but am not able to define the "name" successfully. Thanks!

Comment: `hotels_position['allotment'] = the_data_you_need` will create a new dictionary entry where the key is 'allotment' and the data is what ever you want. I suspect you'll have to perform the getElementsByTagName search inside the `for hotel in hotels` loop.